# Finding FIRST and FOLLOW for grammar

Tags: compiler-construction

Today I am reading how to find First and Follow of a grammar. I saw this grammar:

```
A → Bi|h
B → ejA|Ck|ε
C → m|n|Ap|ε
```

I don't understand how to solve this as there is loop in finding the FIRST here. Can anyone answer this?

I tried solving this but this all are dependent on each other

Comment: Does the thing you're reading give algorithms to find First and Follow? If so, they should be able to handle 'loops', as this is quite common.